# SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18:  in iphone email composer

Tags: iphone, sql, cordova

I have an ios App with email composer and database connectivity. After sending email and coming back to home page I am getting an Error message "security_err dom exception 18". I think the issue is with connecting the database after dismissing the email composer.

Here is my db connection code

```
var connection = null;
var name = "dbname";
var version = "1.0";
var display_name = "displaname";
var size = 200000;
    try{
        if(connection == null)
            connection = window.openDatabase(name, version, display_name, size);
        }
    catch(e){
        alert("SQL Error: "+e);
        return;
    }
```

Can anyone helpme out to resolve it?